# jQuery getJSON and calling file not working in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery

**JS:**

```
var loadNeededDocumentsData = function () {
    $j.getJSON("customermanagement/documentsCheckJSON.do", function (data) {

    });
}

$j(document).ready(function () {
    loadNeededDocumentsData();
});
```

In FF, Chrome code works fine. problem is in IE8, or iE9 that `customermanagement/documentsCheckJSON.do` is never executed. Why? What is wrong in code that works in other browsers but not in IE?

Comment: you might have some luck changing the URL to start with `/`... `"/customermanagement/documentsCheckJSON.do"`

Comment: is this an ajax call?

Comment: musefan can not be / because it is not in root but in subdomain which must be automatically recognized. Ram yes it is ajax call

Comment: Try looking at the network tab on the developer tools. In Chrome and in IE: Is the request going out? Is the response coming in? Are they happening the same way? Maybe the problem lies within the headers or the response mime type.

Comment: Just a hunch... Could this be a compatibility view issue, try turning compatibility view off from IE, tools - compatibility view.

Answer (score 2):

IE8 doesn't support CORS in the [XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) object which is what jQuery. IE8 uses [XDomainRequest object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd573303%28v=vs.85) which [jQuery doesn't support](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8283) by default. So, try this in your code:

```
jQuery.support.cors = true
```

Something useful here is this idiom:

```
jQuery.getJSON(URL, 
  function(data) {
    alert(data);
  }
)
.error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(errorThrown); })
;
```

It will give you an idea what the error is when the getJSON failed.  In this case it's probably going to say something about no transport.